# Swift error when using 'listAll' : 'Expected gs://... to be a child element of gs://...'

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-storage

When using `.listAll` to retrieve a list of items in the root folder of the storage bucket, I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Expected
> gs://MyBucketName/ to be a child element of
> gs://MyBucketName/filename'

This only happens when listing the root folder, and not when listing a subfolder.

The request is called as follows:

```
// Storage Reference
let storageReference = Storage.storage().reference().root()

// List all items
storageReference.listAll { (result, error) in

    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    // Check what was found
    for item in result.items {
        print(item.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: I literally copy and pasted your code and it works for me. You should probably add a return in the error checker. Also, that code won't show any folders so your need to do `for prefix in result.prefixes` for those.